# Need to combine these two commands

Tags: bash

So I am trying to make a script to call the timestamps from repo files to compare them between environments to see if they have been synced within a certain amount of time these are the two commands I have.

```
$echo;
for environment in dev test production; do
   echo "${environment}"
   ls -la /opt/maintenance/repos/epel/"${environment}"/*/x86_64/repodata/*filelists.sqlite.bz2
   echo -e '\n'
done
```

This pulls the files I need to compare for the different environments (test, dev, production).

now how would I "pipe" or enter these files into this snippet to compare the timestamps

```
file1=$(stat -c %Y .bash_profile)
file2=$(stat -c %Y .bashrc)
date_diff=$((( ${file1} - ${file2})/86400 ))
echo "${date_diff}"
```

I was thinking originally to pipe the output of the first command onto an array and then having that be how the second command calls it. Am I thinking this through correctly?

Comment: Jay, I'm confused. Why the elaborate `for environment...`? Why not just `while read -r name; do #whateverwithname; done < <(find {dev,test,production} -type f)`? You do not want to use `ls -al` as part of the command see, e.g. see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) Also, where are `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` figuring in? Are these just used to get a `date_diff` to use with the other files? (I guess I'm not clear on what you are asking...)

Comment: They are just example files that I used to test the commands. That is where I would out the variable for the files.

Comment: If you want to find all files (or a subset of files named `"**bz2"`) under each of the directories `dev,test,production`, then use the `find` command (it's a bit perplexing at first), but when you need to find, use `find`... Since you feed the `while` loop with the output of `find` you have one filename per-interation you can run any command you like on. In my example `while read -r name; do file1=$(stat -c %y "$name"); ...; done < <(find {dev,test,production} -type f)` it will find all files under `dev,test,production` and then execute any command within the loop with the filename in `name`.

Comment: To get the difference between two files, just use a `prev=` variable and on the first iteration, `if [ -z "$prev" ]; then prev="$name"; continue; fi` and on the next iteration your have both `$name` and `$prev` (the previous filename) to compare, etc..

Comment: It's not clear which timestamps you want to compare, or what the output from the first loop looks like. Do you expect exactly one output from each iteration of the `for` loop?

Comment: `echo -e '\n'` is a really brittle and nonportable way to say `echo` without any arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This contains a fair amount of guesswork, but perhaps you are looking for

```
stat -c '%Y %n' /opt/maintenance/repos/epel/{dev,test,production}/*/x86_64/repodata/*filelists.sqlite.bz2
```

The output should be easy to pass to Awk to compare the first field on each line and possibly print in some human-readable form.  If you want to compare each subsequent one against the first, maybe pipe to

```
... | awk 'NR==1 { age=$1; next }
    { $1 = ($1-age) / 86400; print }'
```

The brace expansion `{dev,test,production}` is a Bash feature which is not portable to other shells.  The `stat` options you used aren't portable either so it looks like you are on Linux anyhow.

Comment: Where are you getting the 86400 from? What does it stand for? I am assuming it's something to do with seconds. But it isn't any normal amount of time from what calculations I've done.

Comment: I literally lifted it from your question. It's 24*60*60 i.e. the number of seconds in 24 hours.

Comment: Yeah had a dense moment there. They come more often than not.

Comment: Yes and no, yes the problem is solved. No as in I didn't use this exact answer but it put me on the right track